# config.php for xampp permissions

Tags: permissions, xampp

I had to reinstall xampp, it works almost perfect. 
But in Joomla I have to manually create the config.php due to a permissions isue. Same for WP, I have to create manually wp-config.php. Also I have to remove the install folder of Joomla manually. 
In WP I can't install themes, I have to give ftp credentials.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your file permissions are wrong. cd in to your http directory (the one containing the wordpress and joomla folders, and run the following:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. How? I followed [this](http://www.codebind.com/linux-tutorials/install-xampp-ubuntu-18-04/) tutorial. I missed one step, hence my problem. Also read [this](https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/ubuntu-linux-tutorials/how-to-fix-permission-of-htdocs-folder-in-ubuntu-linux.html) tutorial, for giving httpd.conf the right permissions.

- http://www.codebind.com/linux-tutorials/install-xampp-ubuntu-18-04/
- https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/ubuntu-linux-tutorials/how-to-fix-permission-of-htdocs-folder-in-ubuntu-linux.html